# react native horizontal flatlist not scrolling

Tags: arrays, react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I have a horizontal flatlist but it's not scrolling

I don't know the reason yet

Can someone help me?

```
              <FlatList
                data={dashboardData}
                contentContainerStyle={{
                  width: '100%',
                  paddingHorizontal: 30,
                  flex: 1,
                }}
                keyExtractor={key => key}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                horizontal
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              />
```

Comment: you've set width 100% to contentContainerStyle (which is the style of inner container), would make the inner container's width = container's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update [`contentContainerStyle`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle) to,

```
...
contentContainerStyle={{
  //Remove `flex: 1` and `width` property, that will wrap all of the child views.
  paddingHorizontal: 30,
}}
...
```